# azure portal website publish

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a problem with publishing my web app into azure free web app preview (or whatever it's called) https://tryappservice.azure.com I am using Visual Studio 2015 web deploy to publish my project. After publishing is done, in the Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online), I can see wwwroot folder, but there is no approot folder, or any other folder where my web app files would be. After launching the url that is given to me, nothing loads. I checked with Chrome Developer Tools and there is nothing that loads to the site, not even the wwwroot folder and the error is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

https://github.com/ziombo/KIS

Comment: Does VS report a successful app publish?  Are you using the downloaded publishing profile from the Azure portal?

Comment: Yes to both questions. It return successful and the profile I use is loaded automatically after choosing "Microsoft Azure App Service" and picking subscription.

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of app you're trying to publish? e.g. regular ASP.NET apps are drasticially different from DNX / ASP.NET Core apps.

Comment: It's ASP.NET CORE MVC 6 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 500 error typically indicates an application error. Can you get it to run locally? If so, I would suggest adding some error checking to see if you can trap the error and print out error details.

If you are connecting to a database, have you deployed your database to Azure as well? If so, can you connect to your database on Azure from a local copy of your web app?

Once you have redeployed your web app (with error handling), make sure that the database connection string (if applicable) is correct in the cloud. If you are using environment variables, you'll have to make sure that the Web App on Azure has the proper variable defined, with the correct connection string.